# Basics of in-app email?

Tags: iphone, email, ios

What classes am I looking in to?  I'd like to allow the user to to "order" something via email in the app. i would like to use a modal view to show an email form which is pre-poulated.

Can someone please explain the process of sending an in-app email like this or refer me to the proper documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's iPhone SDK documentation has some information about using in-app email:

- [*Using the Mail Composition Interface*, iPhone Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedFeatures/AdvancedFeatures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH14-SW50)
- [`MFMailComposeViewController` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) (this is the view controller a user sees when writing an email)

Answer (score 0):

The link "Using the Mail Composition Interface" from the answer above redirects to "About iOS Programming" and I don't think it is a good start point for someone who needs an in-app mail composing tutorial.

There is a sample project on Apple's site that can give you a very good understanding of the process if you need such and it also provides ready to go code that you can integrate in your project with a bit of coding. The sample project - [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MailComposer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008865-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)